# Why does chmod +w not give write permission to other(o)

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, chmod

When I run `chmod +w filename` it doesn't give write permission to `other`, it just gives write permission to `user` and `group`.

After executing this command

```
chmod +w testfile.txt
```

running `ls -l testfile.txt` prints

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravi ravi 20 Mar 10 18:09 testfile.txt
```

but in case of `+r` and `+x` it works properly.

I don't want to use `chmod ugo+w filename`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/718782/158442

Comment: If you don't want to use `ugo`, use `a`.

Comment: yes, but i just want to know why `+w` not working.

Comment: That's why I left two comments.

Comment: @muru.  You claim in your `askubuntu` answer that  you reference above that "This behavior is POSIX-mandated, and so, not a bug".  Please be advised that POSIX Application Usage text is non-normative and is therefore not mandated by POSIX.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 noted. One comment (and notification) is enough. Better yet, why not suggest an edit with the correct phrasing?

Comment: @fpmurphy1, it's here, under "extended description", a section not marked as informative: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html "If who is not specified, the file mode bits represented by perm ..., except for those with corresponding bits in the file mode creation mask ..., shall be set."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Your specific situation

In your specific situation, we can guess that your current `umask` is `002` (this is a common default value) and this explains your surprise.

In that specific situation where `umask` value is *002* (all numbers octal).

- `+r` means `ugo+r` because `002 & 444` is `000`, which lets all bits to be set
- `+x` means `ugo+x` because `002 & 111` is `000`, which lets all bits to be set
- but `+w` means `ug+w` because `002 & 222` is `002`, which prevents the "o" bit to be set.

### Other examples

- With `umask 022` `+w` would mean `u+w`.
- With `umask 007` `+rwx` would mean `ug+rwx`.
- With `umask 077` `+rwx` would mean `u+rwx`.

### What would have matched your expectations

When you change `umask` to `000`, by executing

```
umask 000
```

in your terminal, then

```
chmod +w file
```

will set permissions to ugo+w.

### Side note

As suggested by ilkkachu, note that `umask 000` doesn't mean that everybody can read and write all your files.

But `umask 000` means everyone that has some kind of access to *any* user account on your machine (which may include programs running server services ofc) can read and write all the files you make with that mask active and don't change (if the containing chain of directories up to the root also allows them).

Comment: umask 000 means everyone that has some kind of access to a user account on your machine (which may include programs running server services ofc) can read and write all the files you make with that mask active and don't change, to be clear

Comment: _"+r means ugo=r"_ -- no, it doesn't, it means to set the `r` bit for those parties where the umask allows it. This is clearly stated in the manuals of e.g. GNU chmod and FreeBSD chmod, as well as the standard. Same for `+x`. For `+w` you're right, for the case of that particular umask.

Comment: Also, setting umask to `0` _doesn't_ mean that everybody can read and write _all_ your files, since many applications create files that are particularly private with mode `0600`, meaning that the group and others don't get any access, regardless of the umask.

Comment: @ilkkachu +r means ugo=r, this was related to the situation described in the question. That was not general.

Comment: @Debian_yadav, that's exactly the point: the `umask` is an important part of how `+r` behaves, not a sidenote. Besides, even assuming umask `002`, `chmod +r` doesn't mean `chmod ugo=r`, it means `chmod ugo+r`

Comment: This answer, while partly true, is misleading and should not be *as is* the accepted answer. It could be improved. By comparison @chazelas answer is totally true, yet still a little short for someone not familiar with `umask`.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon why don't you explain, how it is misleading?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav Basically, readers of this question will often be beginners, and often only read the beginning of your answer. Comments already pointed out the problems. As a result, I offered an edit to the answer.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon thanks for the suggestion, I approved it, but as beginners will not understand it, it doesn't mean it is misleading.

Answer (score 30):

With:

```
chmod +<perms>
```

the perms are added to *user*, *group* and *other* but with the umask still applying. It makes sure the file is not granted more permission than a newly created file would.

If you want to add the perms to *user*, *groups* and *other* regardless of the umask, use

```
chmod a+<perms>
```

which is short for

```
chmod ugo+<perms>
```

Comment: It means that +x and a+x are not equal.

Comment: I like to have links: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html „If none of these are given, the effect is as if (a) were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.“

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to whom you are giving the permissions to, such as `other`, by using `chmod o+w testfile.txt`

Comment: yes, but i think `+w` gives permission to all( user, group and other).

Comment: To give permissions to all users, use `chmod a+w testfile.txt`. Use `u` for user, `g` for group, `o` for other, and `a` for all.

Comment: if `chmod a+w filename`, `chmod +w filename` and `chmod ugo+w filename` are alternative to each other then why not just use `+w`