# What does chmod -u do?

Tags: permissions, chmod

By accident I ran `chmod -u filename` and it removed all of the permissions I had on `filename`.

The man page does not reference a `-u` option. Experimenting I was able to conclude that it removes not all permissions, but just read and execute access, leaving write access intact.

So what does this do exactly?

---

My conclusion above is wrong, I now think that what it does is remove the permissions that the owner has, from all categories.

---

I think the behavior is analogous to `a=u`, only it is `-` instead of `=` and `a` can be dropped just as it can with, for instance, `a+x`.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a basic question that is not in the man page.

Comment: "The format of a symbolic mode is  `[ugoa...][[-+=][perms...]...]`,  where `perms`  is  either zero or more letters from the set `rwxXst`, **or a single letter from the set `ugo`**" (GNU chmod man page); POSIX is fairly obscure, but defines a "permcopy" production for the same effect.

Comment: @MichaelHomer It doesn't say what it does.

Comment: @y_wc "Instead of one or more of these letters,
       you can specify exactly one of the letters **ugo**: the permissions granted
       to  the  user  who  owns the file (`u`), the permissions granted to other
       users who are members of the file's  group  (`g`),  and  the  permissions
       granted  to  users  that are in neither of the two preceding categories
       (`o`)."

Comment: Yes, I read that. I don't see that it mentions what it does. It says that I can specify one of those letters. Specifying, for instance `u`, I'll be specifying the permissions granted to the user who owns the file. But it doesn't say what it does. What does specify even mean?

Comment: Somewhat relevant https://askubuntu.com/questions/718777/strange-behaviour-of-sudo-chmod-rwx-does-not-remove-group-write-permissions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not an option, but a standard (but uncommon) way of specifying the permissions. It means to remove (`-`) the permissions associated with the file owner (`u`), for all users (no preceding `u`, `g`, or `o`). This **is** documented in the man page.

[GNU chmod's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) documents this as:

> The format of a symbolic mode is `[ugoa...][[-+=][perms...]...]`, where `perms` is either zero or more letters from the set `rwxXst`, or a single letter from the set **ugo**

and later

> Instead of one or more of these letters, you can specify exactly one of the letters ugo: the permissions granted to the user who owns the file (`u`), the permissions granted to other users who are members of the file's group (`g`), and the permissions granted to users that are in neither of the two preceding categories (`o`)

So `-u` means to remove (`-`) whatever permissions are currently enabled for the owner (`u`) for everybody (equivalently to `a-u`, except honouring the current umask). While that's not often going to be very useful, the analogous `chmod +u` will sometimes be, to copy the permissions from the owner to others when operating recursively, for example.

---

It's [also documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17_13), but more obscurely defined: the permission specification is broadly `who[+-=]perms` (or a number), and the effect of those are further specified:

> The permcopy symbols `u`, `g`, and `o` shall represent the current permissions associated with the user, group, and other parts of the file mode bits, respectively. For the remainder of this section, `perm` refers to the non-terminals `perm` and `permcopy` in the grammar.

and then

> `-`
>
> ...
>   If **who** is not specified, the file mode bits represented by perm for the owner, group, and other permissions, except for those with corresponding bits in the file mode creation mask of the invoking process, shall be cleared.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. The POSIX documentation is convincing. The GNU however... Please see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508104/what-does-chmod-u-do#comment938678_508104) comment of mine. I don't see how what comes after "So" follows from what's before. `perms` can be `u`, that I got. Yes, `u` specifies the permissions or the owner. But how does it follow that `-u` removes the permissions of the owner (modulus `umask`) from all users?

Comment: Because that's what `-` always does: it removes the specified permissions from the specified class of users. `-u` is exactly analogous to `-w` or (closer) to `ugo-u`.

Comment: I was about to say I didn't come here to discuss documentation and that I was happy to just understand what's going on, but the docs just clicked. Thanks.

Comment: Could I trouble you with another `chmod` documentation question? Let me know if you think this deserves a seperate question. "and =  causes  them  to  be added and causes unmentioned bits to be removed  except that a directory's unmentioned set user and group  ID  bits  are  not affected. " This, to me, is saying that, given a directory whose owner has only write access,  `chmod u=rx directory` will leave the owner's permissions as `rwx`. But that's not what happens, instead they become the expected `r-x`. Am I misinterpreting someting?

Comment: It's saying that the setuid/setgid (`s`) bits are left alone if you don't mention them, and anything else you didn't specify is removed.

Comment: Ohhhh. I didn't realize it was referring to setuid and setgid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is little bit similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429424/255251.

```
chmod -u file_name
```

doesn't removes all permission, but it consider `umask` value.

```
umask
0022
ls -l file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4 Feb 25 15:17 file
chmod -u file
chmod: file: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------
ls -l file
-----w--w- 1 user user 4 Feb 25 15:17 file
```

Now change umask value

```
umask 777
chmod 777 file
chmod -u file
chmod: file: new permissions are rwxrwxrwx, not ---------
ls -l file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4 Feb 25 15:17 file
```

Comment: Instructive, good to know and very useful, but I think this isn't *really* the issue, although it is very much related. Thanks.